# Primefaces fileUpload is not called

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I am using primefaces 5.0 and jsf 2.2 and I keep getting a NullPointer error.

.xhtml file:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <p:fileUpload  fileUploadListener="#{mBKnjiga.uploadSlike}" mode="advanced"  allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;" />
```

Bean:

```
byte[] image;
...
public void uploadSlike(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
image = IOUtils.toByteArray(event.getFile().getInputstream());
}
```

web.xhtml:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>primeFacesFileUploadFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>primeFacesFileUploadFilter</filter-name>
<servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<context-param>
<param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
<param-value>auto</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have added the jars for commons-io and commons-fileupload just in case. Also I have tried to  upload the picture using the mode="simple" the way it was explained in their showcase but it didn't work. I also tried it without the commons fileupload.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `allowTypes` value is breaking the component. `allowTypes` expects a regular expression. Try `allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"`

Comment: Tried it, and it still isn't working. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure then. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the primefaces version. Primefaces 6.1 works just fine.